# Batch file stops executing after mvn command

Tags: shell, maven, batch-file, command, maven-archetype

```
set homepath=%userprofile%
set a=%1
set b=%2
set c=%3
set uuid=%4
set zipDirectory=%5
set pluginDirectory=%6
cd %homepath%\%a%
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=file://%homepath%/.m2/repository
```

Everything works up to here, then the command lines stop executing. It doesn't print the 1, nor subsequent commands.

```
1
c
b
c
%uuid%
Y
cd %homepath%\%a%\%b%
mvn clean install
cd %homepath%\%a%\%b%\%b%-plugin\target
jar -xvf %zipDirectory%
cd %homepath%\%a%\%b%\%b%-plugin\target\META-INF\maven\%c%\%b%-plugin
copy pom.xml + %pluginDirectory%
cd %pluginDirectory%
rename pom.xml %b%-plugin-1.0.0.pom
```

**Question**: Is there anything about maven I don't know about that interrupts a batch process? Does it not understand to execute the command with a lone number 1?

Comment: In Batch files in windows you need to run `mvn` and other batch files via `call mvn ...`...

Comment: Cool. Is that the same for commands like `jar`, `copy` and `rename`?

Comment: Hmm... Even when I call it still doesn't execute the `1` directly after the mvn command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When invoking Maven from a batch file to create a new project via archetype you should be aware of the [**interactive mode**](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/examples/generate-batch.html) of the execution, that is, Maven will prompt for certain values or ask for confirmation.

It seems in your case this is not the desired behavior. You should hence pass via command line some [options](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html) of the `generate` goal and the specific archetype and then run either in batch mode via the `-B` standard Maven option or via `-DinteractiveMode=true`.

From [official documentation](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/examples/generate-batch.html) you should pass

> - The archetypeGroupId, archetypeArtifactId and archetypeVersion defines the archetype to use for project generation.
> - The groupId, artifactId, version and package are the main properties to be set. Each archetype require these properties. Some archetypes define other properties; refer to the appropriate archetype's documentation if needed

Hence in your case:

```
call mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=file://%homepath%/.m2/repository -B \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.sample -DarchetypeArtifactId=artifact -DarchetypeVersion=1.0 \ 
-DgroupId=your.groupid -DartifactId=your.artifactId -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT \
-Dsomething-else=value
```

Note: `\` added for readability, you don't actually need it

Comment: Makes sense. When I scripted this with AutoItX I could simulate the keystrokes but this is different. I therefore assumed I could run the command lines from the batch file into the interactive inputs when that was incorrect. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

try to execute that command like this. Then next command will execute as expected

```
CALL mvn <command>
```

Comment: CALL fixed the problem and I did not need to use the proposal with the maven parameters